# eth.coinbase gives Error: not supported

Tags: addresses

I created an account, it's
0x1ed6e4623c84d86a170b9a500a2e6ea1d29cd292
and sent some ETH to it, but when I try to check my balance using the geth docs, which mention eth.coinbase, it says:

```
Error: not supported
at web3.js:3104:20
at web3.js:6191:15
at get (web3.js:6091:38)
at <unknown>
```

What's going on? I'm getting a sinking feeling in my stomach...

Comment: Show your actual code please.

Comment: etherscan.io says that there *are* funds in that account. What commands are you trying to run?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. SImply calling `web3.eth.coinbase` throws this error; there is no more relevant code.

Comment: `eth.accounts[0]` worked! You would think that the documentation would show this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the answer is 
`eth.accounts[0]`
It's due to a misuse from a long time ago that eth.coinbase was the way to access the reward address from mining. But in light mode, the coinbase is not enabled. Therefore it throws an error.
accounts is the real way to access the wallets. 0 is the first, 1 the second, etc.